# Mac script to check if there is any wifi connection

Tags: bash, macos, wifi

I have searched and am having troubles finding an answer, im sorry if this is a novice question...

I am creating a program to automatically reconnect to my VPN and mount required drives in the event of a disconnect. So far, it works perfect (checks every 60 seconds or so for the VPN)

Problem comes when I am not near wifi, it keeps yelling at me that it cannot connect. Is there a bit of code that exists to simply check if I am connected to the internet before running the rest of the script, and if I am not connected to the internet, to just leave me alone until I reconnect? Most of what I can find looks to ping a website (which im not adverse to doing, especially if i can use it to ping the VPN) but does not seem to work in the background without notifying me that it still cannot see the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a few ways you can verify internet connectivity; the simplest of which is to just `ping` an external host (one that you expect to be up), then check the status code.

> Replace `www.google.com` with `your.vpn.host` or any *host* you desire in the following examples.

```
host="www.google.com"

ping -c1 "$host" &> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # connection is UP
else
  # connection is DOWN
fi
```

Alternatively, you can use `nc` to specify a custom port number and connection timeout period:

```
# Note: w/ the macOS BSD version of `nc` you use the `-G` flag rather than the `-w` flag to specify the connection timeout.

host="www.google.com"
port=80
timeout=5

nc -G$timeout -z "$host" "$port" &> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # connection is UP
else
  # connection is DOWN
fi
```

If you don't want to rely on *external* commands, and instead decide you want to leverage `bash` native TCP sockets (and also specify a custom port number and connection timeout period):

```
host="www.google.com"
port=80
timeout=5

echo > "/dev/tcp/$host/$port" & pid="$!"
{ sleep "$timeout"; kill "$pid"; } &> /dev/null & 
wait "$pid" &> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # connection is UP
else
  # connection is DOWN
fi
```

If you simply want to check if you are connected to a WiFi network on a specific interface (macOS **ONLY**), you can use:

```
# Replace `en0` with the interface you want to check
networksetup -getairportnetwork en0

# There is no convenient status code check that I am aware of here. You can 
# save the output to a variable and grep for the word: "off"

# I don't think this is what you need but to check if Wi-Fi is `enabled` use:
networksetup -getairportpower en0

# Again, you will need to grep for the word: "off"
```

> For a more robust alternative, I would suggest you take a look at a simple bash utility I wrote called [`check`](https://github.com/clarketm/check) written specifically for checking the connectivity of proxy servers. **Spoiler**: there is no magic here though; under-the-hood I am just leveraging bash native TCP/UDP sockets, albeit wrapped with a convenient set of options and insightful usage documentation.

Finally, one slightly esoteric alternative that I have employed in macOS launchd daemons to pause execution (i.e. endlessly loop) until an internet connection is available:

> **CheckForNetwork** is shell function located in `/etc/rc.common` to check inet addresses. It is a useful utility but will not ensure internet connectivity (only ip address assignment) as opposed to the aforementioned alternatives which **will** verify connectivity.

```
. /etc/rc.common

CheckForNetwork
while [ "${NETWORKUP}" != "-YES-" ]; do
  sleep 60
  NETWORKUP=
  CheckForNetwork
done
```

Comment: Constructive criticism is always preferred over blind downvotes, thanks.